# Bit-timing not yet defined for mcp2515

Tags: pi-4, can-bus

I'm trying to set up my mcp2515 with a VP230 Can transceiver for can communication. so far, I am able to connect the mcp to my RPI using SPI bus 0 and to set it up as can0 in RPI. However, when I tried to set the communication up, it seems like it was set up when I run the command "ip -d -s link show can0" However when I run the command "dmesg | fgrep -i can" it showed that the can bit-timing is not yet defined.

I'm pretty new to RPI and Can devices, so any advice would definitely help! Thanks

Able to establish bit timing for MCP2515 spi bus.

[image: image of terminal message]

edit!
it seems like my spidev is set up for spidev0.1 and spidev6.0
my /boot/config.txt file for spi is as follows
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi6-1cs, cs0_pin=18
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0, cs0_pin=8, oscillator=8000000, interrupt=25

I'm not sure if is it due to the spidev difference that causes my spi bit-timing to not be set.

[image: spidev img]

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000`?  Or whatever matches your specific network?

Comment: hi sanders, thanks for the comment. yes i did tried it out. which is why my "ip -d -s link show can0" has a bitrate of 500000. which i find it surprising why i am able to set the bitrate for the can device.

Comment: Ok, see if this works:  `sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000 dbitrate 2000000 berr-reporting on fd on`.  If that doesn't work, I know this seems obvious, but restart the raspberry pi and re-do the configuration commands.  If that doesn't work - have you checked the wiring & power supply?

Comment: hmm the terminal returns
"RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported"
But surprisingly when i just run "sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000" it is able to set the can device bitrate. but when i use "dmesg | fgrep -i can" it shows that the can bit-timing is not yet defined.

Comment: Run `candump can0` to start listening for CAN messages on the can0 interface, and see if there are any error messages or other issues reported.

Comment: i can run candump with no issues.
i have 2 rpi with the exact same set up and i am able to send between both of them but not to other can devices

Comment: Check the SPI interface: Make sure that the SPI interface is properly enabled on your Raspberry Pi and that it is connected to the MCP2515. You can check this by running the `lsmod` command to see if the "spi_bcm2835" module is loaded. Also, make sure that the SPI device is enabled in the Raspberry Pi configuration by running `sudo raspi-config` and checking the "Interfacing options" menu.

Comment: SPI configuration via sudo raspi-config is enabled.
as for lsmod, i could see that spi_bcm2835 is there, but under the used by column its "0"
in my /boot/config.txt
i have included a line for bcm, "dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835"
upon boot up, it has a pop up "fail to load overlay 'spi-bcm2835'"

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit the /boot/config.txt file from

> dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,interrupt=25,oscillator=8000000

to

> dtoverlay=mcp2515,spi0-0,interrupt=25,oscillator=8000000

It seems like its due the kernel version change.
Source of information is from another forum ([https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/issues/359#issuecomment-1119666048](https://I%20tried%20to%20edit%20the%20/boot/config.txt%20file%20from%20dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,interrupt=25,oscillator=8000000%20to%20dtoverlay=mcp2515,spi0-0,interrupt=25,oscillator=8000000.%20It%20seems%20like%20its%20due%20the%20kernel%20version%20change.%20Source%20of%20information%20is%20from%20another%20forum%20https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/issues/359#issuecomment-1119666048))

Answer (score 0):

Per the data sheet https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP2515-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001801K.pdf the High-Speed SPI Interface can opperate upto 10 MHz in SPI Modes 0,0 and 1,1. It also has a crystal or oscillator input, you need to program for that.Hopefully this will get you started. I cannot read the fuzzy screen shots you posted so this is a bit of a SWAG.

As you probably know you will need a receiver on the CAN network when trying to transmit a message.